# ActionBarActivity is deprecated Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am new to android-programming. I installed the SDK and added the library and when I create a new project I get this error:

> ActionBarActivity is deprecated

I use android support library 22.2 and android 5.1.1(API 22).

```
package com.example.ww;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;//problem
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { //problem

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate - the referenced link pertains to Android Studio -- this is an issue pertaining to Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) with [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).

You don't *need* to do anything, just because it's deprecated doesn't mean it's not functional. It means it will not be supported in the future. Eclipse should be giving you a warning, not an error.

Here's the current souce code of ActionBarActivity, from [the Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.java):

```
/**
 * @deprecated Use {@link android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity} instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public class ActionBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

---

To clarify, all you need to do is replace

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

with

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Comment: when i replace it with AppCompatActivity it works , but every time when i create a new project i had to replace it ??

Comment: You shouldn't need to change it, typically the IDE would give you a warning, not an error.

Comment: but please how can edit in eclipse to show me AppCompatActivity

Comment: yes Sir it works but when i create an other project the ActionBarActivity show up again ??

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the default new file, sorry. I'd suggest using Android Studio, it's the new official IDE for Android. They've patched that a couple versions ago, so it will create new support activities extending `AppCompatActivity`. It's also a much better IDE.